# draw a circle over a image in html5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

html code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function start() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 69, 50);
        //draw a circle
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(100, 75, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.stroke();
     };

    image.src = 'xy-coordinates.jpg';                 
  }
</script>
</head>
<img id="myImgId" alt="" src="xy-coordinates.jpg" />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="start()"> 
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="393"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to draw a circle on an image dynamically once I click the button.

The problem is after clicking the button, I'm getting an extra image (with the circle drawn) displayed on the screen rather drawing on original image.

My requirement is to draw a circle on an image which is already displayed.

UPDATED

```
<script>

function Draw(){
var img = document.getElementById("theImg");
var cnvs = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

cnvs.style.position = "absolute";
cnvs.style.left = img.offsetLeft + "px";
cnvs.style.top = img.offsetTop + "px";

var ctx = cnvs.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250, 210, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.stroke();
}


</script>

<img id='theImg' src='xy-coordinates.jpg'>
<input type='button' value='Draw' onclick='draw()' ><br>
<canvas id='myCanvas' width="700" height="393"></canvas>
```

when < br > is used in html tag befor or after canvas there comes a huge distance betweein image and button r any tags i place in there. how to rectify it ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to create one more image because canvas in fact is an image by itself. Place your canvas on top of the source image by setting its position to absolute, left and top same as the source image:

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImgId");
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
c.style.position = "absolute";
c.style.left = img.offsetLeft;
c.style.top = img.offsetTop;
```

Then just draw into canvas:

```
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.stroke();
```

UPDATE:

```js
function Draw(){
  var img = document.getElementById("theImg");
  var cnvs = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  
  cnvs.style.position = "absolute";
  cnvs.style.left = img.offsetLeft + "px";
  cnvs.style.top = img.offsetTop + "px";
  
  var ctx = cnvs.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(250, 210, 200, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#00ff00';
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
#draw-btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 16px 3px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id='draw-btn' type='button' value='Draw' onclick='Draw()' />
</div>
<img id='theImg' src='http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02351/cross-eyed-cat_2351472k.jpg'>
<canvas id='myCanvas' width='536px' height='536px'></canvas>
```

Comment: No. That didn't work :( image is completely hidden. when i click the button, button gets moved to top and image is not dispayed.

Comment: Of course it works! See the sample in my answer update.

Comment: Fine :) 
BTW, I'm just publishing the article 'Mastering images with HTML5 canvas'. The first part is ready, the next is upcoming in the closest days. You are welcome to read: http://www.web-plus-plus.com/Articles/mastering-images-html5-canvas-1

Comment: sorry for troubing u again. but now the problem is in html tags when i have <br> before or after canvas, I'm getting a huge sapce between two html tags. In the above code there is a huge space between image and button. how to rectify it ?

Comment: OK, let's make it a little bit more elegant. See the updated :)

Comment: thank you soo much for your patience and clarity of expanation, you are awesome :) BTW i gone through your article. It's cool ! Want you to post more article. Eager to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing one image on canvas, and second image with "img" tag (already displayed). you can't draw circle with canvas, on HTML tag.

Comment: is there any possiblity to do it dynamically ?

Comment: No you just can move <img> element on <canvas> with css, (but it's not good way), but draw canvas element on html tag not. You should draw both on Canvas (better way)

Comment: i'm not getting you. both on canvas ?

Comment: I mean, if you want to draw circle on image , you should draw both (image and circle) with canvas (not with HTML tag).