# Draw a circle on an image on respective coordinates

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

How do I draw a circle on an image given coordinates. For eg I have a 700x400 image and want to draw a circle on the image centred at (320,200) point.

Comment: We could try [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458818/draw-a-circle-over-a-image-in-html5-and-javascript/28459329). Are you still looking for a solution ?